# Can someone explain why they took in s+1?

Tags: c++

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
char s[1000007]; 
int main()
{
    int T, n;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--)
    {
        long long ans=0; 
        scanf("%d%s",&n,s+1);
        for(int i = 1;i <= n; ++i)
            for(int j = 1; i * j <= n && s[i * j] != 49; ++j)
                ans += i * (s[i * j] == 48), s[i * j] = 50;
        printf("%lld\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused about what the `s+1` part means because earlier in the code, they declared `char s[100007]`. Would it just mean take in s and add 1 to it?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 2):

`s` is a pointer. Doing a `scanf` to `s+1` reads the input into the memory pointed to by `s` starting at the byte *after* the byte that `s` points to (that is, `s[1]`). This is done because the for loops all start at 1 (and *that's* because we want the answer to give a count, thinking the way humans think).